# Entity-relationship diagram for car rental (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

I'm new to the forum, and I've tried searching for an answer but I can't find specifically what I need. Here is the deal. For a collage project I have to make a car rental web application. I've come up with an idea what should it do and for that I've created my ER model. But I'm not sure if it's good. The thing is not to do very complicated application, but to cover one RAD tool. I've ended up with Iron Speed. Here is the idea of the application.

Customer can come to website of car rental, and make a reservation, beside other things he can choose start date, end date, and car.
Employee can edit, and see all the reservations, and also make a reservation if customer comes personally to "office". He can also add new cars to database (type of car + model etc.) and make a bill for each reservation.
Administrator can add new employe and everything else (but that's his main thing let's say).

Table USERS has all the information about employees and administrator, and roles has roles in it, and they need to have a bridge table (this is needed because of the RAD tool to make user roles permissions).

Information about customers won't be needed separately (this can be a bad thing but let's leave it that way), and we have their information in REZERVATION table.

NOTE - I know it would be logical to connect employee with reservation (one to many) but that gives me the problem that customer needs to select employee when making reservations, same with car adding, it's stupid to select employee to add car... I mean its logical that someone needs to put car into database. For bill it is logical so I know who made it.
Car type and car are connected with reservation that way so I can make filtering type - > model later in drop down menus.

Link to jpeg: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50541281/SnapShot_121124_220841.jpg

Link to mysql workbench file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50541281/car%20rental.mwb

I would really appreciate it if someone who knows can modify it as needed, or put some bridge tables if needed. Or just type notes here so that I can adjust my schema myself.

Just to add, this is only let's say need to see version of ER model since I've just translated it from my language to English, so all attributes, types, etc are not there.

Comment: Looks like your model jpg is a 404... can you update the link?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you may be best using a join during the sql statement to get the information. Assuming the employee doesn't have anything to do with this account until later in the process (after booking the car) you should leave it to the other interface. When the cars are booked an employee should log in and check, if they process the order then add the EmployeeID to the table then. Leave it without relationship, it seems messy but it is a quick solution.